# Intern to Full-Time, placed as contractor until hiring freeze is over

Tags: software-industry, internship, education, benefits, fulltime

While attending a local Community College, I accepted an internship with a company.

Fast Forward 6 months the company offered me a full time position. (w00t w00t)

*This is where things get tricky.*  My company is part of a larger corporation that has a hiring freeze.  Therefore there is no capacity for my company to hire full time employees.  To get past this, they hired me as a contractor as of January 3, 2017.  They increased my pay rate to match what would of been my salary pay.  UNFORTUNATELY I do not get benefits.  My company has an amazing 100% tuition reimbursement program after you work full-time for 1 year.

I'm in my last semester at the community college and want to continue my education at a much larger university that is ($$$$).  However I can't afford it unless I can access the Tuition Assistance Program that my company has.

I have talked to HR multiple times about using my time as a intern, then as a contractor towards the "1 year full time" requirement so that I can continue my education.  However H.R. says my time as an intern and a contractor will **NOT** count towards the hours needed to access the Tuition Assistance Program.

I have also heard whispers of other employees using this program before working for 1 complete year.

1. Is it worth going over her head to the H.R. Branch Manager?
2. Should I just suck it up and wait the extra year?

What should I do? I'm not sure what the best path is.

**EDIT:**
There is no guarantee WHEN I will be transferred to full-time.  H.R. just tells me they continue to send my requests each month.  They project it will happen January of 2018.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere My options are limited.  I still don't even have my AA degree yet from the community college, I was extremely surprised this company wanted to hire me yet pay me a really good salary(50k) for someone with no degree

Comment: I had tuition assistance a few years ago from a Fortune 500 company. My manager just had to check boxes on my re-imbursement forms requirements - there was no validation. I had left before the required two years but my manager just checked the box that said there was no re-imbursement issues. Maybe check with whoever would sign your form to see about flexibility.

Comment: your a contractor but only getting what you would as  a FTE that's a big red flag id look for another job - you should getting 2x/3x as a contractor

Comment: @Neuromancer I understand what your saying, however I'm still in school getting my degree.  So I don't think that the conversation about getting paid more as a contractor does not apply to me.  I think that it would apply to people who have degrees and experience

Comment: @Humanid1652487954543 no you should get more as a contractor to make up for lack of benefits irrespective of how experienced you are

Comment: What do you think @JoeStrazzere, do you agree with what Neuromancer is saying?  Is it normal for contractors to receive extra pay for benefits not received? Even if it someone with a situation like me with no degree and no experience.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I value your opinion....thanks for the input!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First - **Stop trying to deal with HR.** They are just going to follow policy and you already know what the policy is.

Who is your manager/supervisor? Who made the decision to hire you despite your "lack of qualifications"? That's the person you need to talk to and explain your situation. You need the people in your management who value your work enough to go to HR and tell them to make an exception. A good company can bend a few policies to get and keep the right person. Maybe they can get that for you, maybe they can't, maybe they can convince someone higher up who can.

If not, only you can decide if you want to wait or seek other employment. Personally, I would be looking for a position with educational reimbursement and other benefits. My own experience as a new grad was similar, I was hired right out of school on contract with no benes because of a "hiring freeze". I let them know that while I loved the work, I needed a "real" job with benefits. I was actively interviewing both inside and outside the company. I received and accepted an offer from another employer and I gave my 2 wk notice.

Comment: I agree 100%.  I worked as a contractor for an employer who was in a hiring freeze for almost two years. I went to my boss and told him I was about to lose my health insurance benefits (which were carried over from my last company), and would need to leave to maintain health benefits.  He went up the chain of command (all the way to HQ in Australia as it happens--I am in the US), and they approved hiring me.

Comment: Marked as answer because: 
"Who is your manager/supervisor? Who made the decision to hire you despite your "lack of qualifications"? That's the person you need to talk to and explain your situation. You need the people in your management who value your work enough to go to HR and tell them to make an exception"